# How to upload a file from PC to AS400 machine using FTP Command

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange

Need a Help about FTP command PUT.

Requirement is to upload a file from Windows PC to AS400 machine. Here is the command (running as a batch file) I am using:

```
open ipAddress
Kishore  //user
pwd      //password

quote RCMD CRTLIB LIB(TESTXA) TEXT('TESTXA Java Application Source')   //Successfully creates TESTXA library 

quote RCMD CRTSRCPF FILE(TESTXA/QJAVASRC) RCDLEN(200) TEXT('Java Source File') //Successfully creates source file QJAVASRC under TESTXA library 

put "D:\Shared\JavaTest\ClobTest.java" /QSYS.LIB/TESTXA.LIB/QJAVASRC.FILE/CLOBTEST.MBR  // Generating error 'ftp: bind : can't assign requested '

quote RCMD CHGPFM FILE(TESTXA/QJAVASRC) MBR(CLOBTEST) SRCTYPE(JAVA) TEXT('ClobTest') // Not executing due to previous command error

bye
```

Please suggest what am doing wrong with PUT command??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Oh dear.  Doesn't the machine have IFS with `/tmp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smells like a firewall.  Before doing the PUT, try setting passive mode.  `quote pasv`

Answer (score 3):

Specify namefmt 0 before put. Namefmt 0 tells ftp to use library/object naming.

Answer (score 3):

Check the client [proxy settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Bind: Can't Assign Requested Address from Ftp.exe Using Winsock Proxy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164395)

> If the IP address of an external interface on the Proxy Server is in the LAT, it is considered by the proxy client to be internal. Because the client computer does not have an interface with the same IP address as the external IP address of the Proxy Server, you get the above error message.